# Interchanging limits of sums and infinite series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Is this statement always true?

\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f\left(k\right)= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}f\left(k\right)
\end{align}

Also, would this statement always be true?

\begin{align}
&\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f\left(k,n\right)= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}f\left(k,n\right)
\end{align}

Thank you so much for the help. :)

Comment: What is the definition of  $\displaystyle{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f\left(k\right)}$ ?

Comment: In the first formula does not fit into the title of the question. The same concerns the second one. Perhaps you wanted $$\lim_n\sum_{k=0}^\infty f(k,n)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \lim_nf(k,n)$$ The last formula does not hold in general. Additional assumptions are necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second statement is not guaranteed to hold. You should be able to define $f(k,n)$ using only $0$'s and $1$'s in such a way that
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty f(k,n) = \infty \quad \text{yet} \quad \sum_{k=0}^n f(k,n) = 0$$
for all $n$.

Comment: e.g. $f(k,\,n)=[k>n]$.